# Sending/Creating An Object To/In A Separate Class in Java

Tags: java

How might I use a method inside one class to create an object in a separate class?

IE: I have a class extending `JFrame` with an `ActionListener` inside it. On button click, the `ActionListener` should then create an object within the Main class rather than the `JFrame` class. Is this possible? If so, how is this accomplished?

Comment: "_Is this possible?_" Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a static method  in main class (or if u have access to object of main class in jframe even a instance method would do), that creates the object of that class. and then call it from your action listener.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of this. Thank you so much!